# What is 'use ClassName' in Ruby (vs include, require, load)

Tags: ruby, sinatra

What does `use SomeClassName` do in Ruby?

In the course of migrating a 'flat/classic' Sinatra app to use separate classes for each controller, I came across a blog entry suggesting at one point to `require` then `use` the classes.

```
#app.rb a Sinatra classic app that formerly had all the routes in app.rb, now moved to separate controller classes
...
require "./app/controllers/foo_controller.rb"
require "./app/controllers/bar_controller.rb"

use Foo # a class with a set of routes
use Bar # a class with a set of routes
...
```

I've somehow managed to use Ruby, Sinatra, and Rails fairly productively for years without a `use` statement, and adding such a common word as `use` to any google query doesn't narrow the search.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain, what, *precisely* is unclear to you about the (admittedly terse) documentation of `Sinatra::Base::use`. That way, the Sinatra developers can improve the documentation, so that future programmers don't have the same problem as you did.

Comment: As my question indicates, I was (mistakenly) assuming from the context in sample code in a blog post about implementing controller classes that 'use' was a Ruby method, until Sergio below kindly pointed out it was a Sinatra method. Which explains why no amount of googling enabled me to find 'use' in Ruby docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is 'use ClassName' in Ruby (vs include, require, load)

In ruby this means nothing. It's a part of sinatra API.

If those controller files still contained "classic app"-style code, you wouldn't need to use `use` here. Simply requiring them would have worked.

But since they're now technically separate Sinatra apps (as far as I can guess the content of the files), you need to mount them in the main app. This is done by registering the apps (and their routers) as middleware.

This is the method in question: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/6f15fba2790ebdf4d1215cebf425dea2ea3130ea/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1430-L1433